# Return roads that extend entire length of bounding box from OSM data

Tags: postgis, extents

Lets say I have a bounding box of lat/lon of:

```
Left -122.27671
Bottom 37.80445
Right -122.26673
Top 37.81449
```

I have OSM Data of all roads/ways/nodes...etc within this bounding box. Is it possible to return roads that extend the entire length of the bounding box? Or that intersect with two different areas of the bounding box?

Or is there a better way to solve this: I'm essentially trying to filter out small side streets. Maybe I could do this by the `type` of way or by the total length of the way?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

1. Decompose the box with [`ST_Boundary`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html) into the border lines
2. Calculate the [`ST_Intersection`](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersection.html) of it. That'll return a `MULTIPOINT`.
3. Count with the points inside the `MULTIPOINT` [`ST_NPoints`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_NPoints.html)

Sample code.

```
SELECT ST_NPoints( ST_Intersection(ST_Boundary(box), line) )
FROM ( VALUES
  (-122.27671, 37.80445, -122.26673, 37.81449)
) AS t(l, b, r, t)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeEnvelope(l,b,r,t) AS box
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
      ST_MakePoint( (l+r)/2, b - 0.1 ),
      ST_MakePoint( (l+r)/2, t + 0.1 )
) AS line;
```

We generate a line that exceeds the bounding box right down the center with those exact coordinates you've provided.

You can get the points instead of just the count of the points, using [`ST_DumpPoints()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html)

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working, and when I use ST_DumpPoints this is what it returns 
`("{1,1}",0101000000D36A48DC63915EC034A2B437F8E64240)`
`("{2,1}",0101000000D36A48DC63915EC0A375543541E84240)`

What is it referencing?

Comment: The {1,1} is the position in the parent geometry. Look at the example on the bottom of the page. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html

Comment: how do I link this back to a specific way or road?

Comment: See which roads `ST_Crosses()` that specific point of intersection. There may be more than one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to PostGIS and doing spatial work. Are the dump points referencing the bounding box or are they referencing lines that intersect with the bounding box and their position? I'm having a hard time tying this back to OSM data to find which roads intersect the box.

Comment: I'd rather teach you how to fish even if it's annoying. In the query above replace `ST_NPoints` which counts points, with `ST_AsText` which will dump the arguments NPoints uses. You tell me. See any lines there?